# write()/read() in a Client/Server, pthread application in C returns -1 always when on non-main thread?

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets, pthreads, client-server

So, I have this client/server application, where the server has a producer/consumer architecture. I have 2 functions that handle writting and reading to the socket. The main thread of the server (the Producer) handles connections and passes socket descriptors via a Stack to the second thread, the Consumer, for processing.

The problem is, whenever I try to write() or read() the socket from a different-than-main thread, it always returns -1 and causes a `Connection reset by peer` error on client and `Transport endpoint is not connected` error on the server. Surpirsingly, it works perfectly when socket is read/written from the main thread.

Why does this happen? Is this official behaviour? How do I go about replying to the client with the Consumer thread? I don't believe it's because of the code I wrote, since the Consumer thread only calls the read/write-to-socket functions.

If you have any suspicion on which part could be a culprit, ask me to post some of the code.

EDIT:

```
typedef struct s_stack {
    int * c_stack;
    int base;
    int top;
    unsigned char is_full;
    unsigned char is_empty;
    int max_size;
} s_stack_t;
s_stack_t stack;

void * producer_routine(void * arguments) {

    /* socket(), bind(), listen(), etc.,
       socket fd on "socket_fd",
       new connection fd on "new_fd" */

    for(;;) {
        new_fd = accept(socket_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&client_addr, &clen);

        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        while (stack.is_full) {
            pthread_cond_wait(&stack_not_full, &mutex);
        }
        if (stack.is_full){
            push(&stack, new_fd);
            pthread_cond_signal(&stack_not_empty);
        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    }
    close(new_fd);
}

void * consumer_routine(void *args) {
    for(;;) {
        int socket_fd;
        /* same mutex lock as above, just reversed, pop to socket_fd */
        write_a_message_to_client(socket_fd);
    }
}

int main() {
    stack_init(&stack, 1024); // (s_stack_t * stack, int max_size)
    pthread_t tidp, tidc;
    int prc = pthread_create(&tidp, NULL, producer_routine, NULL);
    int crc = pthread_create(&tidc, NULL, consumer_routine, NULL);
    stack_destroy(&stack);
    return 0;
}
```

The client just sends a message, and waits to receive one. If `write_a_message_to_client()` is called within any of those threads, even with the socket_fd passed as a parameter, I get the same errors. If it's called directly in main, it has no problem.

EDIT #2:

I tested this, and found my stack implementation to not work on Cygwin. Cygwin adds gibberish after the 3rd element for some reason, so the socket fds were invalid. Also, I was testing this in a Debian 6 VM and the server was crashing after connection from client. But I tested it in Arch, Kali and my Uni servers (Debian 7) and works as it should have been. A whole lot of trouble for a whole lot of nothing. Thanks Cygwin!

Comment: My best guess without seeing the code is that you're somehow closing or disconnecting the socket descriptor in the main thread before the second thread gets to use it, but that's far from definitive (all else apart, the error would be more like EBADF than ECONNRESET or ENOTCONN if you were using `close()`).

Comment: Perhaps the main thread is calling shutdown() on the socket somewhere?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I'm using close() on new connection file descriptor, but outside the server loop. I've also tested specific parts of the code to no avail. I've also verified that, the connection fd gets passed correctly to the new thread. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner No. I haven't used shutdown() anywhere in the code.

Comment: Can you create an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) or
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/))
that shows the problem. It needn't do very much except have two threads, pass descriptors between the threads, and generate the error when the descriptor is used.  I don't think we're going to be able to solve your problem without a small program that reproduces the problem.  Note that it is far from unheard of for the process of producing an MCVE to show you the resolution of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should not call `stack_destroy()` until after both threads have completed.  I think your entire program is running using a destroyed stack.

Use `pthread_join()` to wait for the threads to complete before destroying the stack.

Comment: Yes I had used pthread_join() I just forgot to add it. Anyway, the program seems like it isn't working in CygWin and crashes on a Debian 6 VM. It works pretty much anywhere else.

Comment: It makes it very difficult to help when you don't show the real code (or, rather, a small subset of the real code that reproduces the problem). My suspicion is that you're getting lucky where it does work and the non-working platforms are trying to tell you something.  Get [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org/) and see whether that tells you anything.